# wget script to connect, wait if successful, continue if no connection

Tags: bash, perl, wget

I have to create a script that sends a wget contact message to all devices on our network. wget connects to a url and this trigger the endpoint to contact a server.

The problem I have is I need to be able to send the command to each IP address on the network and if the connection is successful do noting for 30 seconds then move on to the next url in the list. However if the connection isn't successful I want the script to move on to the next url with no pause.

Currently I'm using a bash script to send the command with a pause=30 in-between url's,  connection attempts set to 1 and time-out set to 1. this works OK for the connections that are successful but it also hangs on the addresses that are not.

Any advise on how I can pause on success and move on after time out on dead addresses?

This is the command I'm currently running,

wget --connect-timeout=1 --tries=1  http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8085/contact_dls.html/ContactDLS
sleep 30
wget --connect-timeout=1 --tries=1  http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8085/contact_dls.html/ContactDLS
etc etc etc

thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO, please show your coding efforts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would probably load the urls into an array and iterate through the array.  Something like this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my @urls = qw(test.com url.com 123abc.com fail.aa);

foreach my $url (@urls){
    my $check = `wget --server-response $url 2>&1 | grep HTTP/ | awk '{print \$2}'`;
    #if there is a successful response you can set the sleep(3) to sleep(30) for your instance.
    if($check){
        print "Found $url -- sleeping 3 seconds\n";
        sleep(3);
    }
    else{
        print "$url does not exist\n";
        #If the url does not exist or respond it will move on to the next item in the array.  You could add a sleep(1) before the next for a 1 second pause
        next;
    }
}
```

Of course this is assuming that you are using linux.  The urls could be loaded another way as well, I don't know how your current script it getting them.  The above is an example and you of course would need to be adjusted to fit your environment

Comment: Hi thanks for this, we are using a linux environment, I will look at trying this tomorrow,   Thank you !

Comment: I added comments to the above code to make it a little more clear as to what I was doing

Comment: Hi Ed, I have used your code and added the url's as above with a space in-between, when I run the script it just hangs on the first url, and never moves on after the sleep time. Any ideas?  Thanks !!

Comment: try to test it by commenting out but the if and else and replacing the my $check with a simple system("wget $url"); to see if the wget is even doing what it's suppose to.  From there we can expand on it

Answer (score 1):

You don't need wget for this task - everything can be done in Perl.

Simply use code like this:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request;

my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent;
$ua->timeout(1);
my $req = new HTTP::Request(GET => $url);
my $res = $ua->request($req);
if ($res->is_success()) {
    print("Connection to '$url' was OK");
    sleep(30);
} else {
    print("Cannot access '$url'");
    sleep(1);
}
```

This will hit your url, but will timeout in just 1 second.

Comment: Hello, this would hit the url and move on after one second, but I need to add a 30 second pause if the connection is OK but a 1 second pause if the device is off / dosent respond.    thanks, Lee

Comment: Just check `$res->is_success()` - I added this to code snippet

Comment: Brilliant, I will give this a try when I'm back in the office tomorrow. Thank you !